# Cannot SSH using hostname, but can use the IP

Tags: ssh, internal-dns

Inside a VPN, there is a DNS server with a known zone of "gitlab". When attempting to do anything other than SSH (and things using SSH - scp, git) to this hostname, it works, but using SSH rejects the connection.

Here is a terminal session that should show the issue demonstrated fairly well:

```
$ nslookup gitlab
Server:     172.31.27.193
Address:    172.31.27.193#53

Name:   gitlab
Address: 172.31.25.132

$ ssh git@gitlab
Permission denied (publickey).
$ ssh git@172.31.25.132
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Benjamin Hutchins!
Connection to 172.31.25.132 closed.
$ ping -c 1 gitlab
PING gitlab (172.31.25.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.25.132: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.530 ms

--- gitlab ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.530/0.530/0.530/0.000 ms
$ ping -c 1 172.31.25.132
PING 172.31.25.132 (172.31.25.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.25.132: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.570 ms

--- 172.31.25.132 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.570/0.570/0.570/0.000 ms
$ ssh -vvv git@gitlab
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "gitlab" from file "/home/bhutchins/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 45:e9:a6:c4:f4:8d:14:06:4a:ea:de:68:04:69:c2:f4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "gitlab" from file "/home/bhutchins/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/bhutchins/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'gitlab' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bhutchins/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fccfbc60360),
debug2: key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/bhutchins/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can't seem to find anyone reporting a similar issue. The server I'm running this terminal session is fresh Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS. The server it's trying to talk with by the hostname `gitlab` is on the same VPC this server is. Any ideas what may be causing this mishap?

Comment: Does `ssh -v git@gitlab` show anything useful?

Comment: `Connecting to gitlab [::1] port 22` you are connecting to localhost?

Comment: what is in your ssh_config(s)?

Comment: @Halfgaar ssh -v git@gitlab would just be less verbose than the ssh -vvv git@gitlab I did above.

Comment: @Jakuje There is nothing in my user ssh config, and the system's is default settings.

Comment: @Jakuje I'm not trying to connect to my localhost, but indeed something is misconfigured. Any idea why it might try do connect to localhost?

Comment: yes, you are trying. You must have somewhere mapping `gitlab` name to `::1`. So the other possibility is `/etc/hosts`

Comment: What if you do `ssh -4 git@gitlab`?

Comment: @Halfgaar That works, using `ssh -4 git@gitlab` works; but `ssh git@gitlab` does not.

Comment: @bhutchins then there's something wrong with your ipv6 setup.

Answer (score 1):

@Jakuje and @Halfgaar helped point out the issue. It was due to `ssh` using IPv6, and the internal private DNS server had the `AAAA` record for IPv6 misconfigured to `::1` for every record.

After fixing the bind zone files, things started working.